# pygame wont upgrade to latest version :ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame==2.0.1

Tags: pygame

Iam trying to install latest version of pygame to run it on python 3 but when I type this in terminal

> sudo pip3 install pygame==2.0.1

I get the following error

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting pygame==2.0.1
  Using cached pygame-2.0.1.tar.gz (5.5 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-f2aop58i/pygame_f50a3b4ef6f34184b95da3eb41799e8f/setup.py'"'"'; _file='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-f2aop58i/pygame_f50a3b4ef6f34184b95da3eb41799e8f/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-73xjipr
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-f2aop58i/pygame_f50a3b4ef6f34184b95da3eb41799e8f/
    Complete output (31 lines):
    
    
    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using UNIX configuration...
    
    WARNING:root:Some pygame dependencies were not found. Pygame can still compile and install, but games that depend on those missing dependencies will not run. Use -auto to continue building without all dependencies.
    Missing dependencies
    
    Hunting dependencies...
    SDL     : found 2.0.14
    FONT    : found
    IMAGE   : not found
    IMAGE SDL_image.h libSDL2_image.so ['/usr/include', '/usr/include/SDL2', '/usr/local/include', '/usr/local/include/SDL2', '/usr/X11R6/include', '/usr/include/SDL2'] ['/usr/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/X11R6/lib', '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/X11R6/lib', '/usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu', '/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/', '/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/']
    MIXER   : not found
    MIXER SDL_mixer.h libSDL2_mixer.so ['/usr/include', '/usr/include/SDL2', '/usr/local/include', '/usr/local/include/SDL2', '/usr/X11R6/include', '/usr/include/SDL2'] ['/usr/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/X11R6/lib', '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/X11R6/lib', '/usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu', '/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/', '/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/']
    PNG     : found
    JPEG    : found
    SCRAP   : found
    PORTMIDI: not found
    PORTMIDI portmidi.h libportmidi.so ['/usr/include', '/usr/include/SDL2', '/usr/local/include', '/usr/local/include/SDL2', '/usr/X11R6/include', '/usr/include/SDL2'] ['/usr/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/X11R6/lib', '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/X11R6/lib', '/usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu', '/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/', '/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/']
    PORTTIME: not found
    PORTTIME porttime.h libporttime.so ['/usr/include', '/usr/include/SDL2', '/usr/local/include', '/usr/local/include/SDL2', '/usr/X11R6/include', '/usr/include/SDL2'] ['/usr/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/X11R6/lib', '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/X11R6/lib', '/usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu', '/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/', '/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/']
    FREETYPE: found 23.4.17
    
    ---
    For help with compilation see:
        https://www.pygame.org/wiki/Compilation
    To contribute to pygame development see:
        https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
    ---
    
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c7/b8/06e02c7cca7aec915839927a9aa19f749ac17a3d2bb2610b945d2de0aa96/pygame-2.0.1.tar.gz#sha256=8b1e7b63f47aafcdd8849933b206778747ef1802bd3d526aca45ed77141e4001 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pygame/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame==2.0.1
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pygame==2.0.1
```

It gets downloaded but after the downloading is finished it throws the above error
Any help would be greatly appreciated
PS: I tried to upgrade pip , tried to install a different version(2.0.0),tried to install it in virtual environment. nothing worked and showed the above error

Comment: Latest version is 2.3.0 why are you trying 2.0.1? https://www.pygame.org/news

Comment: thank you. I was using 2.0.1 earlier so I tried to install the same version. I have now installed the latest and it installed just fine. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

As of 23/3/2023 the latest version of pygame is 2.3.0

https://www.pygame.org/news

It seems that solved the issue.